# Fundamental group of space identifying $S^1 \times S^1$ with $RP^2 \subset RP^3$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

So this is an old exam question: Consider $RP^2 \subset RP^3$ and let $f: RP^2 \rightarrow S^1 \times S^1$ be a continous mapping. Let $X = RP^3 \cup_{f}S^1 \times S^1$, what are the homology groups/fundamental group of X?

My intuition would be the following: I know that $RP^3 = RP^2 \cup_gD^3$ where $g$ is the double cover of $RP^2$ by the boundary of $D^3$. So i think $X$ is $D^3$ glued to $S^1 \times S^1$ by some map from the boundary to the torus (specifically by $f \circ g$). I would suspect that $X$ has the same fundamental group as $S^1 \times S^1$ perhaps by Van Kampen, but I'm not sure how to apply it without knowing $f$ explicitly. And what about the homology groups?

Comment: I didn't think long but $f_* : \pi_1(RP^2) \to \pi_1(S^1 \times S^1)$ is the zero map as there are no torsion elements in $\pi_1(S^1 \times S^1)$. Does it help ?

Comment: I think with this observation you can prove that $\pi_1(X) \cong \pi_1(S^1 \times S^1)$ as you suspected.

Comment: @N.H. Sorry I'm not familiar with torsion elements, is it possible to rephrase that somehow in the language of homotopy/homology?

Comment: Ok sure. Fundamental group of $\Bbb RP^2$ is $\Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z$. Since the unique non-trivial element $a \in \pi_1(\Bbb RP^2)$ verify $2a = 0$ it follows that $f_* : \pi_1(\Bbb RP^2) \to \pi_1(S^1 \times S^1)$ has to send $a$ to an element $b \in \pi_1(S^1 \times S^1)$ which verify $2b = 0$. But $\pi_1(S^1 \times S^1) \cong \Bbb Z^2$ and if $b \in \Bbb Z^2$ verify $2b = 0$ then $b = 0$, it follows that $f_*$ is identically zero.

Comment: @N.H. Ok makes sense. How would you proceed with $\pi_1 (X) \cong \pi_1 (S^1 \times S^1)$ then? I think it should be possible to do Van Kampen now for $S^1 \times S^1$ with "a little extra" and $D^3$ with some part of the torus attached so that the image of the generator of $RP^2$ is homotopic to a trivial loop. This obviously isn't very rigid though.

Comment: Yes Van-Kampen is appropriated. I won't be here the few hours but if you are still not convinced this is very rigorous I can write tomorrow the complete argument (but there is nothing more than Van-Kampen + $f_* = 0$).

Comment: Thanks I'd appreciate that, I don't feel very confident about writing a rigid proof for this even though i think i see the idea. What about the homology groups? Is it possible this space is homotopically equivalent to $S^1 \times S^1$? Intuitively it feels like attaching $D^3$ by sending a boundary into something homotopically trivial shouldnt change the type.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $S^1$ is the Eilenberg-Mac Lane space $K(\mathbb{Z},1)$. Thus $[\mathbb{R}P^2,S^1\times S^1]\cong [\mathbb{R}P^2, S^1]\times [\mathbb{R}P^2, S^1]\cong H^1(\mathbb{R}P^2)\oplus H^1(\mathbb{R}P^2)=0$ It follows that $f\simeq \ast$ and

$X\simeq S^3\vee (S^1\times S^1)$

and so the homology groups follow trivially.

Comment: Did you mean $X \cong RP^3 \vee (S^1 \times S^1)$ ?

Comment: Not quite. We get $X\simeq (\mathbb{R}P^3/\mathbb{R}P^2)\vee (S^1\times S^1)\simeq S^3\vee (S^1\times S^1)$. To show this you can factor the (homotopy) pushout square for $X$ using $f:\mathbb{R}P^2\rightarrow \ast\rightarrow S^1\times S^1$ and use the composition of homotopy pushout square lemmas.

Comment: Ok of course, sorry for my stupid comment.

Comment: Need to notice that $H^1(\mathbb{R}P^2, \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, not $0$. Therefore the answer depends on the homotopy type of $f$.

Comment: $H^1(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z})=0$ by, say, universal coefficients.